# How to make app adjusting automatically according to mobile size in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

i am facing issues when application is running in different emulators.. padding,width, resolution, image placement, text alignment issues are coming for different mobiles with different screen size..How to make it adjustable according to screen..

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: [Creating Responsive Apps](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Creating-Responsive-Apps)

Comment: everytime according to screensize we need to give padding or it will automatically?